# Read the value of a complex object

Tags: c#, object

I got an object by this function:

```
    Object temp = NAOData.memory.getData("FaceDetected");
    float alpha = temp[1][0][0][1];
```

The output is describe here: https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/naoqi/vision/alfacedetection.html. But I am not able to extract the data. I got "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: What datatype does `NAOData.memory.getData()` return?

Comment: Did you read the [info for C#](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/dev/dotnet/index.html#naoqi-dot-net)? It shows some type-casting there, so you probably need to read that as well as the documentation for the specific function call you are doing.

Comment: The datatype is ArrayList. I have tried a few ways to cast but failed.

Answer (score 1):

An object is a base type of all reference types.
It has basic things only.

getData returns something that derives from object(or is boxed into one) and therefore you "downcasted" a type into an object and the compiler doesn't know that your new object has an indexer on it.

Try this:

```
var temp = NAOData.memory.getData("FaceDetected");
float alpha = temp[1][0][0][1];
```

Comment: I think some kind of bounds checking should be employed here too. Its a bit presumptious to expect this exact indexing to be ok. I'd try and be a bit more defensive.

Comment: I'm not going into business logic on types that I dont know. It's the developers responsibility to "defend" his code from OutOfBounds exceptions, but your right man..

Comment: Of course, this was aimed at the OP actually not yourself!

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but still got the same error. The datatype of "temp" is ArrayList.

Comment: Then you need to be more specific about what getData returns.

Comment: The document says the data returns as:FaceDetected =
[
  TimeStamp,
  [ FaceInfo[N], Time_Filtered_Reco_Info ],
  CameraPose_InTorsoFrame,
  CameraPose_InRobotFrame,
  Camera_Id
] and for example TimeStamp= [a b] where a,b are float numbers.